# Parse nested json and return the values as string[]

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Can you help me parse the values in 'realEstateProperties' attribute (ex. serial number and economyType.value). Here is a part of the json file:

```
{
    "Entity1": {
        "id": "5f514d20744a1fb",
        "realEstateProperties": [
            {
                "serialNumber": "11",
                "cadastralSections": [
                    {
                        "id": "5f514dc11a1e3",
                        "economyType": {
                            "value": "landRegisterPage.type",
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "landRegisterPage": {
                    "id": "3456",
                    "landRegisterBook": {
                        "abbreviation": null
                    },
                    "note": "LRP",
                    "tags": null
                },
                "propertyTextBlock": null
            }
        ],
        "customFields": [],
```

Here is what I currently have:

```
        public static string[] GetJsonValues(string jsonProperty)
        {
            testCaseName = "Entity1";
            
            FixtureIncident.Root incObject = new FixtureIncident.Root();
            incObject = LoadJSONFile();
            JObject incJson = JObject.FromObject(incObject);
            var attributes = incJson[testCaseName].ToList<JToken>();
            
            var property = attributes.Find(i => i.ToObject<JProperty>().Name == jsonProperty) as JArray;   //returns property=null
            
            string[] Properties = property.ToObject<string[]>();

            return Properties;
        }
```

property returns null and I am not sure how to correct it.
I need to save all the realEstateProperties values in a string[].

I found some similar topics but I couldn't adjust my code so I make it works. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Have you made sure that your `json` is valid before attempting to *try and parse it*? Another question, why not create classes that represent your `json` and then deserialize to those classes?

Comment: Thanks! :)
Yes, the file is valid, I have parsed values like 'id' (on the first level) but I am not sure how to get deeper within the levels.

Comment: What you mean by _I need to save all the realEstateProperties values in a string[]?_ - Save all properties names in a string or all values of all properties? Can you show desired result?